# Can I leave Roxul Safe'n'Sound insulation exposed in a furnace room?

Tags: insulation

Hopefully someone has experience with this insulation.

We are finishing off our basement.  We have one long interior wall that will separate a family room from a furnace/storage room.  The family room side of the wall will be finished with sheetrock, the furnace room side will be left unfinished.  We would like to add some soundproofing in the wall and we were thinking of the Roxul product.

My question is how well do you think the material would hold up on the unfaced furnace room side?  Would it hold up to abuse from getting occasionally bumped by stuff being moved around in the room or boxes pushed against the wall.  I have never used the Roxul product, but it looks like it might "crumble apart" over time?

I don't want to sheetrock that side of the wall and don't really want to mess with plastic sheeting.  If it looks like it would be too fragile to leave exposed I would probably put pegboard over it?

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exposed Roxul Safe and Sound emits a significant amount of airborne particulate.  That is exacerbated by anything that disturbs the surface of the Roxul.  If the Roxul is exposed to air that finds its way into living space I recommend finding some way to cover it up.